# Marp-CLI: How to use a custom theme that imports the default theme

Tags: css, markdown, marp

I am using marp-cli to create lecture slides.
In order to fine tune the slide content, I have created a custom-css that extends some style rules implemented in the marp default css template.

**My objective**:
I want to externalize the css rules in a`custom-theme.css` file and remove them from the `.md`-document in which the slide's content resides.

**The problem**:
When calling the `custom-theme.css` using marp-cli with the `--theme-set` option, I can not specify that my css "extends" the style rules of the default template.

**The question**:
How can I specify that my `custom-theme.css` is defined on the basis of the marp default template?

Thanks in advance for the support.

Answer (score 5):

In case other users experience the same issue, the solution to the problem is stated here in form of an example – provided by Yuki Hattori (the main developer of the marp toolset):

Marp: Markdown.md

```
---
theme: custom-theme
---

# Hello, world!
```

```css
/* custom-theme.css */
/* @theme custom-theme */

@import 'default';

section {
  /* Override default background */
  background: #def;
}
```

Marp-cli:

```
marp --engine ./engine.js --bespoke.progress --watch --theme-set custom-theme.css -- mymarkdo
```

see also:
https://github.com/marp-team/marp-cli/issues/266

Answer (score 4):

There is an on-the-fly theme rendering in **VS Code** without the need of the CLI.

1. install the `marp-team.marp-vscode` extension
2. paste the below snippet into *.vscode/settings.json*
3. change your **.css* paths and styles accordingly

---

```
// Please put `.vscode/settings.json` on your workspace
{
  "markdown.marp.themes": [
    "https://example.com/foo/bar/custom-theme.css",
    "./themes/your-theme.css"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and the tipp about using the VS Code extension. The reason I am using the CLI is that it allows me to add individual (markdown) plugins (e.g. to enable footnotes or have individual boxes for definitions etc. using attribute lists).

Is there a way to enable certain markdown extensions in VS Code?

Comment: Interesting point. What plugin do you use for footnotes?

Comment: Seems like [there is a need](https://github.com/marp-team/marp/discussions/176) and additional markdown features are yet only supported via CLI.